# SSRS Dropdown 'Any' Value not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, parameters

new to this world so looking for help with what I think wold be a simple thing to fix, however me and the guy who is training me on all that is SQL and SSRS cannot figure this out

I have a report within SSRS and SQL which is working perfectly bar one thing

I have a drop down list parameter which has all our customers names, and the report shows volumes of what that customer has obtained so far etc, and for an individual customer, this works perfectly. However, when trying to see the total volumes by choosing 'Any' from the drop down list, it returns no data, rather than returning everything

Can anyone please advise what I could be missing here, or what I need to show you to help resolve this issue

Cheers

Liam

Comment: There could be a few ways to address this but we'll need more details.  Does your dataset use a Stored Proc or is the query directly in the dataset? How are you currently filtering to a single client? Is the filtering done in the dataset filters or directly in the query? Once I have these details I can give you a proper answer.

Comment: Thank you Alan! I really appreciate this,  I am using a stored proc, and currently filtering using a parameter which has a drop down list.  the filtering is done by using the parameters to filter the data from the data set in the stored proc which is then displayed within SSRS

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you Stored Proc parameter is varchar and represents either customer names or an 'Any' value then the following should work.

```
SELECT myField1, myField2 -- etc
FROM myTable t
WHERE (t.ClientName = @myParameterName OR @myParameterName = 'Any')
```

**Optionally Please Note:** Personally I don't use SPs and usually just put the code to grab the data in the dataset. Some companies don't like you doing this but if you are able to do this I think this makes life easier.

If you can put the stored proc code directly in your dataset query then you can make the report more flexible. You can change your parameter to be MultiValue, you don't need and 'Any' value added to your parameter list either and then you can simply do something like

```
SELECT myField1, myField2 -- etc
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.ClientName IN(@myParameterName)
```

SSRS will take all the selected parameter values and inject them into the dataset query correctly, so there is nothing else you need to do. SSRS will also add a 'Select All' option to your parameter in case you want to gran data for everything. The report will work for 1, 2, 10 or all client names.

Comment: Thanks for this Alan.  This worked.  I did have the parameter as 
  
  'AND (([ParentName] = '@Organization) OR '@Organization = ' NULL') (ignoring the quotation marks in front of the '@' symbol as it wouldn't let me post otherwise) which in theory should have worked as this works in all my colleagues data, just not when I've used it in mine.   So thank you for your help here, it's saved a lot of head scratching

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with the answer can you please mark it as accepted. It helps other find solutions when looking for similar issues and it will be listed as answered. Oh, and when posting code or similar in a comment you can the backtick (normally top left key on keyboard) to surround the text (or whatever it's called) `like @this`

Comment: I certainly tried to and up voted it, however because I'm relatively new it doesn't allow me to do anything until my 'reputation' hots 15 apparently